# How to format dates with Pentaho Spoon

Tags: javascript, etl, pentaho

How do I convert the string `03-MAR-2021` to the string `20210303` with Javascript in Pentaho Spoon

```
start_date="03-MAR-21";

var new_startDate= new Date(start_date);

var date= moment(new_startDate).format('yyyyMMdd');
```

Answer (score 1):

See [common date formats](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/Common_Formats)

```
start_date="03-MAR-2021";

var date= str2date(start_date, "dd-MMM-yyyy");

var formatedDateString = date2str(date, "yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the date in a string like '03-Mar-2021' but I need to convert to string '20210303'  (YYYYMMDD) I can make in JScript or directly on Query. But I have problems when I try to

[image: Jscrip Error from ETL .... See screenshot! .]